# Choose what interface to implement at runtime

Tags: java, interface

I'm wondering if, in Java, there is a way to create an object from a class implementing multiple interfaces, but choosing at runtime what interfaces should be implemented. Those interfaces would have no methods, this would be a way to create an object by defining at run time which attributes should have. That is my real problem.
USE CASE: I have a class with a huge number of attributes but the objects created from this class would use only some of those attributes, some will be in common between objects some not, what attributes should be used is decided at runtime by the user. I want to avoid to create objects with a lot of empty attributes.

Comment: You can using bytecode generation or something similarly exotic; but what do you actually want to do with this?

Comment: I guess, you could use a wrapper class with generic type.

Comment: Interfaces establish type. A type has behaviors and attributes (which can be empty sets). Implementation of an interface inherits those behaviors and (static) attributes, and establishes an /is-a/ relationship between subtype (class) and supertype (interface). You can have a subclass of an interface that sports more attributes and behaviors, but those will not be accessible through a supertype reference. So to do what you want, perhaps create a class with what you want and use that as the declared type. The interface will never have them.

Comment: A concrete example or use case would really help.

Comment: I better explained my situation with a use case

Comment: It sounds like your object should just be a Map whose keys are enum values, or, if type safety of values is important, pseudo-enum values with generic arguments like the constants in [StandardSocketOptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Proxy class might be interesting.

I would consider testing capabilities/features:

```
interface Flying { void fly(); }
interface Swimming { void swim(); }

Animal animal = ...

Optional<Flying> flying = animal.lookup(Flying.class);
flying.ifPresent(f -> f.fly());    interface Flying { void fly(); }


Optional<Swimming> swimming = animal.lookup(Swimming.class);
swimming.ifPresent(sw -> sw.swim());
```

Animal need not implement any interface, but you can look up (`lookup` or maybe `as`) capabilities. This is extendible in the future, dynamic: can change at run-time.

Implementation as

```
private Map<Class<?>, ?> map = new HashMap<>();

public <T> Optional<T> lookup(Class<T> type) {
     Object instance = map.get(type);
     if (instance == null) {
         return Optional.empty();
     }
     return Optional.of(type.cast(instance));
}

<S> void register(Class<S> type, S instance) {
    map.put(type, instance);
}
```

The implementation does a safe dynamic cast, as register ensures the safe filling of (key, value) entries.