# Is multi-level inheritance possible Sugar ORM?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sugarorm

I am working on an Android app and have run into a roadblock with Sugar ORM.

For example, let's say I have these classes.

```
public class Animal extends SugarRecord {
  ...
  Animal() {
  }
  ...
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  ...
  Dog () {
    super();
  }
  ...
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  ...
  Cat () {
    super();
  }
  ...
}
```

Now obviously dogs and cats have a lot in common, just like the actual tables I am using. My issue is that when I try to make a Dog or Cat and use the save method on them, the logs say they are persisted buy querying by them does not work, so I am not sure if they are saved in some other table or not.

I have tried these following methods with all the different types of querying methods with no luck.

```
Dog dog = new Dog(...);
dog.save();

Cat cat = new Cat(...);
cat.save();

Animal dog = new Dog(...);
dog.save();

Animal cat = new Cat(...);
cat.save();

// THIS IS THE ONLY ONE THAT WORKS
Animal animal = new Animal(...);
animal.save();

// This only returns the ones saved "Animal animal = new Animal(...)"
Select.from(Animal.class).list();

// This returns nothing
Select.from(Dog.class).list();

// This returns nothing
Select.from(Cat.class).list();
```

Using a migration script I was able to use
`CREATE TABLE DOG(...)`
which blew up and said DOG already exists, which means the tables are being created, just either not populated or not accessible.

When saving new records as Dog and Cat, it prints out
`I/Sugar: Dog saved : 9`
So it should be saving it into something.

Also, when running the queries this is what prints out
`D/SQL Log: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM DOG`

---

Any ideas if inheritance actually works with Sugar ORM, or if there is anyway around it other than having 2 separate classes with redundant data in them? Or if there is any other library that you would recommend to look at to be able to accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902110/984823

Comment: https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/issues/757